# Scroll to particular paragraph on Wikipedia

Tags: javascript, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I am developing an iOS app which presents the first paragraph of a wikipedia article and upon clicking "read more" takes a user to the web-view. Is there some way I can scroll to the second paragraph in the web-view programmatically to allow the reader to resume reading where they left off in the app?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `JavaScript` code:

```
function scrollToPos() 
{
    var el = document.getElementById("yourid");
    el.style.visibility = "visible";
    el.style.display = "block";
    el.scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

When you execute it, the web view should scroll to a div with `yourid` id.

Comment: I figured how to scroll to any element using this:
`var content = document.getElementById('content'),   paragraphs = content.getElementsByTagName('p'); window.scrollTo(0, paragraphs[2].offsetTop);`

However, there istoo much variability in the number of <p> tags preceding content. I think a better strategy would be to search for the last few word in my content and then scroll to there. How do I go about doing that?